# Algorithm to solve an assignment or matching with a constraint

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, variable-assignment, linear-programming

Here is the problem. Suppose we have N workers and N jobs. We want to assign each job exactly one worker. For each worker i, he could do some jobs on some cost. Our goal is to minimize the total cost **on the condition that any single cost should be less than some value.**

For example, 10 workers and 10 jobs. Worker 1 can do job 1 with $0.8, job 2 with $2.3, job 3 with $15.8, jobs 4 to 8 with $100, job 9 with $3.2, job 10 with $15.3.

Worker 2 can do job 1 with $3.5, job 2 with $2.3, job 3 with $4.6, job 4 with $17, etc.

Our goal is to find a matching or we can call it an assignment such that the total cost is minimized but any single cost of the corresponding pair/matching between work i and job i is less than a value like $50.

I would very much like to solve it in **MATLAB** if possible.

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but the problem seems to be very simple. For every Job find the cheapest worker, check if the pair of job and worker is has costs below $50, assign job.

Comment: @DanielR: You are missing something. For example, worker 1 might be more expensive on job 1 than some other, but putting him on job 1 might still give the lowest overall cost (e.g., he's $0.01 extra on job 1, but costs $1.0 extra on any other job).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: You are right, if there is a limit of 1 job per worker. Don't know what is intended.

Comment: @DanielR        That idea is pretty much like the Greedy algorithm. It is useful. I was trying to find the minimum so that may not be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slight variation of the [Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).  To handle your additional constraint that no single job cost should be more than some value, just change all entries in the matrix of costs that are greater than this threshold to a huge value (bigger than the sum of all other entries will suffice), and solve as usual, using e.g. the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for the timely reply. That sounds a great idea. The Hungarian Algorithm can be use for decimal numbers? I will try to implement it using your modified weight.

Comment: @AppalachianMath: You're welcome :) Sure, it works for non-integer costs.  It might be described in terms of maximising a sum of weights, rather than minimising them, in which case just swap all ">"s for "<"s and vice versa (or alternatively make all your numbers negative).

Comment: Got U. I'll do. You have a wonderful night if you are at the middle of a night :D

Comment: Can I ask you a last question? There is a problem when I change all entries that are greater than the threshold into a larger value. The algorithm runs pretty slow when the system size is around 1000. Is there any way that we can get rid of those entries(i.e. matchings) in the process of finding optimal matching?

Comment: Do you mean that it only goes slow if you change the values that are greater than the threshold?  In any case I would expect it to take a while for a 1000x1000 matrix as it's an O(n^3) algorithm!  You might be able to solve the assignment problem using a different algorithm, or get a linear program solver like lp_solve to solve it faster.

Comment: I have not implemented the one without changing entries. I guess it should be faster because there are some matchings I should neglect because the corresponding entries are greater than the threshold. However, if I change those entries, those matchings are possibilities in the optimization process. If linear programming is faster, I will try it as well.

Comment: It's like we should have a constraint x_i <= $50 in the linear programming. This inequality throw away some possible matchings. However, if I use Hungarian Algorithm, those possible matchings are considered even though they will be ignored in the process.

Comment: I wrote that first sentence because I was trying to figure out why you wrote "There is a problem when I change all entries that are greater than the threshold into a larger value" instead of just "There is a problem". I suggested LP because it *might* be faster -- but probably only if the LP solver is smart enough to detect that this is a variant of the assignment problem, and apply a special solution technique for it. Commercial (I)LP solvers, like Gurobi, have a lot of this kind of stuff built in :)

Comment: If you use LP, then you would just omit any pairings that exceed the threshold, rather than setting them to a huge value.  If there are a large number of pairings that exceed the threshold, ordinary simplex or barrier LP methods might well solve the problem faster than the Hungarian method -- have to try and see!

Comment: Do you know if MATLAB has similar functions?

Comment: No I don't sorry -- it's been years since I touched MATLAB.  I seem to recall there was an "Optimization Toolbox" or something for it though.  That might have something like this.

Comment: I see. You mean I could use less variables rather than NxN. I will try it. Thank you very very much for this!!

Comment: That's right -- if there are M invalid (i.e. threshold-exceeding) pairings, you would have a total of N^2-M variables in the LP.  And come to think of it it might need to be an ILP (i.e. variable values constrained to be integer)...  Can't remember if there's some magical property of the problem that guarantees that any optimal LP solution will have all-integer variable values or not.  If not, you'll need to use an ILP solver, which generally take a lot longer to run.